# fedora slow to aquire network ip after startup or cable unplug

Tags: networking, fedora

I've installed Fedora 19, and i'm new to it (I used Ubtuntu until now).

After every reboot, or when i unplug my network cable, the system is slow to pickup the state change, and it takes a long time until the system reloads its IP from my router (i'im using DHCP).

On ubuntu these changes were instantaneous, and resuming from sleep or occasional cable unplugs were handled without problems.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Look at your logs, first.

Comment: what logs? is there a "network connection log"?